# Load Image/Video in UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I want to be able to load images and video to my UICollectionView.

This is my parse query code:

```
var arrayOfDetails = [Details]()
func queryFromParse(){
        let query = PFQuery(className: "currentUploads")
        query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil
            {
                if let newObjects = objects as? [PFObject] {

                    for oneobject in newObjects {
                        let text = oneobject["imageText"] as! String
                        let username = oneobject["username"] as! String
                        let objID = oneobject.objectId!
                        let time = oneobject.createdAt!
                        let likedBy = oneobject["likedBy"] as! NSArray
                        let comments = oneobject["comments"] as! NSArray


                        if let userImage = oneobject["imageFile"] as? PFFile {
                            let userImage = oneobject["imageFile"] as! PFFile

                            let imageURL = userImage.url
                            let OneBigObject = Details(username: username, text: text, CreatedAt: time, image: imageURL!, objID: objID, likedBy: likedBy, comments: comments)

                            self.arrayOfDetails.append(OneBigObject)

                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { self.collectionView.reloadData() }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My struct details:

```
struct Details {
    var username:String!
    var text:String!
    var CreatedAt:NSDate!
    var image:String!
    var objID:String!
    var likedBy:NSArray
    var comments:NSArray
    init(username:String,text:String,CreatedAt:NSDate,image:String,objID:String,likedBy:NSArray,comments:NSArray){

        self.username = username
        self.text = text
        self.CreatedAt = CreatedAt
        self.image = image
        self.objID = objID
        self.likedBy = likedBy
        self.comments = comments
    }
}
```

In my `cellForItemAtIndexPath` i use `let post = self.arrayOfDetails[indexPath.row]` to get the current object, but i have a little problem here. In parse i store the images as File with name "uploaded_image.png", and the videos as File with name "uploaded_video.mp4". How can i make a UIImageView in the UICollectionViewCell if the file is a "uploaded_image.png" and a video player if the file is a "uploaded_video.mp4"?

Or any other suggestions?

Comment: Just create two custom UICollectionViewCells, one for image, one for video.

Comment: How can i load video cell only if there is a video? I found out i can check if the current object is video or image like this: http://pastebin.com/cdepaH56

Comment: You do it in the "cellForItemsAtIndex" method. Dequeue video cell for video parse item, and image cell for image parse item

Comment: Ok now i understand, but how to make the video player fit and how to add it and video video in it?

Comment: That you have to figure out yourself, i can't build the whole app for you. You can start by reading a tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12

Comment: @almas - OK i am close now, but a problem. My code looks something like this(but more code ofc): http://pastebin.com/UAGr8147 but it gives me error: `missing return in a function expected to return "UICollectionViewCell" `